# how can i stop Echo sound in webrtc ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, webrtc

I am working with Webrtc Video streaming.
how to audio echo sound disable?
i write the code

```
-(RTCMediaConstraints *)defaultOfferConstraints 
 {  
     NSArray *mandatoryConstraints =@[                            
          [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveAudio" value:@"true"],                     
          [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"OfferToReceiveVideo" value:@"true"],
          [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"echoCancellation" value:@"false"],
          [[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"googEchoCancellation" value:@"false"]
                                  ];
     RTCMediaConstraints* constraints =[[RTCMediaConstraints alloc]
                   initWithMandatoryConstraints:mandatoryConstraints optionalConstraints:nil];
     return constraints;
}
```

but,it's not working.
how can i stop or disable echo sound?

Comment: Maybe try `initWithKey:@"echoCancellation" value:@"true"]` ? On second thought, these look like peer connection options. Instead you want to set getUserMedia constraints. Echo cancelation should be on by default though, so make sure you're not outputting your own sound locally.

Comment: i have set this constraints but it's not working

Comment: `defaultOfferConstraints` are the wrong constraints (they're for PeerConnection). You want constraints for getUserMedia. They're probably set somewhere else. Also echo cancellation is on by default, so something else is wrong. Echo cancellation won't catch 100% of echo if you blast recorded sound out the speakers at the same location.

Comment: i also set but not working

Comment: when i connect web to mobile then echo sound generate but mobile to mobile not echo sound generate.